# SOQL query 'WITH USER_MODE' then update

Tags: apex, security, user-mode

I fetch ObjectA records with a SOQL query 'WITH USER_MODE'.
Then I modify those records and want to update them in user mode

I am not sure if the previous 'WITH USER_MODE' command is enough to prevent modification from unauthorized profiles (like profiles with read but no update permissions) .

- If yes : so I just need to write : 'update myModifiedRecords';
- If no : I need to explicitely say I want the user mode by writing : 'update as user myModifiedRecords;' (if so, should I understand that 'WITH USER_MODE' in SOQL query only check the Readable permission ?)

Answer (score 3):

`WITH USER_MODE` in a SOQL query just checks for read permission on the object and fields. To check for edit permission when updating, you will indeed need to use `update as user`.

Comment: Thanks ! I have the same question for 'With Sharing' keywords on a class, it checks only read authorisation right ? So when updating, I again need to explicitely specify wanted mode ?

Comment: `with sharing` enforces sharing rules, so it will apply to DML statements as well. Object level permissions from profiles and permission sets can only be enforced using `WITH USER_MODE` and `as user` (or by manually checking the permissions)

Comment: Thanks again ! Is there a link explaining in details all of this ? For example in 'with sharing' official documentation (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm) they don't speak about DML statements in such a context... maybe at another place ?

Comment: There isn't any other documentation from Salesforce, but there a few other explainers online if you search for it. However, none of it is great. I think the best thing to do would be to test it yourself to convince yourself of how it works.